# where to get the system library's source code?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering where to get the javaScript system library's source code? I need to check the String object's implementation.

Comment: For which JavaScript implementation?

Comment: just use console.log and if that doesn't help then try getting the code if it's not Native Code.

Comment: @amnotiam that's also my question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code for V8 (Chrome's implementation and also the one used by Node.js) [is on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/Source).

You can download Mozilla's SpiderMonkey's source [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/Getting_SpiderMonkey_source_code) or [browse the Mercurial repo](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/21c84409902e/js/src).

WebKit's JavaScriptCore [is on WebKit.org](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore), of course.

There are [other implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines) that are out there, but these are the big three. Microsoft's implementation for Internet Explorer (Chakra) is closed-source naturally.

Comment: Thanks Jordan! It looks like js library is built using C, is that true? I thought the library should be written using js too.

Comment: [V8's implementation of String](http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/3.7/src/string.js) appears to be self-hosted. SpiderMonkey and JSCore are both in C++.

Comment: it looks nice for V8 implementation

Answer (score 0):

ECMA-Script ( which Javascript is technically a dialect of ) is defined in the [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) standard. In an ideal world that is how the string object is implemented ( assuming you have the proper version number ).